# Sql Server Data Tools Data Comparison fails when connecting to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

When using the Sql Server Data Tools Data Comparision tools a few of us here are unable to do comparisons when the source is an Azure database.

The error we get is below:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Data information could not be retrieved because of the following error:

Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: conn

Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: conn
```

The connection test works fine.  I've tried creating a new connection.  As a side note if I do data compare with a non-Azure source things work fine.

SQL Server Data tools version is 12.0.50512.0

We can access the server using SSMS without any problems.

Comment: can you share the version of SQL Server Data Tools with us? you can see this under HELP>About Microsoft Visual Studio. I just tried this and did not run into any problems. Would love to help.

Comment: added.  Also mention that we can use SSMS fine.

Comment: SSDT version 12.0.50512.0 supports Data Compare with Azure SQL Database. Can you please share more detail about your SQL Database? What is the Pricing Tier of the database and schema complexity? e.g. number of tables and views. size of database.

Comment: Had similar problem with publishing .sqlproject to Azure V12 database. One of the environments' users had no access to master database. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be a permissions issue but I was able to diagnose it using the details available at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/740e3ed8-bb05-48f7-8ea6-721eca071198/publish-to-azure-db-v12-failing-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-conn?forum=ssdt

Gathering an Event Log for SSDT

- Open a new command prompt as Administrator.
- Run the following command

  - logman create trace -n DacFxDebug -p "Microsoft-SQLServerDataTools"
    0x800 -o "%LOCALAPPDATA%\DacFxDebug.etl" -ets
  - logman create trace -n
    SSDTDebug -p "Microsoft-SQLServerDataToolsVS" 0x800 -o
    "%LOCALAPPDATA%\SSDTDebug.etl" -ets
- Run whatever the target/issue scenario is in SSDT. Go back to the command prompt and run the  following commands

  - logman stop DacFxDebug -ets
  - logman stop SSDTDebug -ets
- The resulting ETL files will be located at %LOCALAPPDATA%\SSDTDebug.etl & %LOCALAPPDATA%\DacFxDebug.etl and can be navigated to using Windows Explorer.

Comment: As this is the first result from a google query I thought I would add the solution here.  Yes it is a permissions problem.  Schema compare trying to query the master database which by default an azure user does not have access to.  Simple add the user (no permissions just add the user) to master on the azure instance and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limitation. Ref - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh272693(v=vs.103).aspx

**Check whether the Firewall Rule is open for this connection. If not, then add the current client IP to allowed IP addresses of that SQL Azure DB**

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I have already compared a local DB before hand (in the same session) then try to compare an Azure DB. I find there is some strange lock preventing login on the Azure SQL DB.

Shut down Visual Studio and reopen and it should connect ok.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio worked for me, it is incredible that Microsoft has not solved this issue almost a year later since Alex reported this fix I'm still running into this issue.